# Running tensorflow random-forest but getting value error?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying tensorflow random forest but I'm getting the following error
params =

```
tf.contrib.tensor_forest.python.tensor_forest.ForestHParams(num_trees=100, max_nodes=1000,num_classes = len(le.classes_),num_features = 119)
classifier =tf.contrib.tensor_forest.client.random_forest.TensorForestEstimator(params)
classifier.fit(x=X_train, y=y_train)
```

`ValueError: Tensor conversion requested dtype float32 for Tensor with dtype float64: 'Tensor("concat:0", shape=(?, 119), dtype=float64)'`

But it works when I run `scikit-learn`

```
clf = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=n_estms, n_jobs=n_jobs)
clf = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

Update:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.20, random_state=42)
```

Updated :
Tried this style but still its not working

```
input_fn  =  numpy_io.numpy_input_fn(
      x=X_train.astype(np.float32),
      y=y_train.astype(np.float32),
      num_epochs=None,
shuffle=True)
classifier.fit(input_fn = input_fn,steps=None)


ValueError: Features are incompatible with given information. Given features: Tensor("fifo_queue_DequeueMany:1", 
shape=(128, 119), dtype=float32), required signatures: TensorSignature(dtype=tf.float64, shape=TensorShape([Dimension(128), Dimension(119)]), is_sparse=False).
```

Data Set :

```
X_train,y_train,len(X_train),len(y_train)

(array([[ 3.3042e-01,  2.4995e-01, -6.0874e-01, ...,  3.0400e+02,
          5.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00],
        [ 4.2466e-01,  8.5174e-01,  8.6044e-01, ...,  1.0000e+00,
          7.8000e+01,  1.0000e+00],
        [ 6.1890e-01, -1.1185e+00,  5.8483e-01, ...,  1.4000e+01,
          7.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00],
        ...,
        [ 9.0512e-01,  1.3008e-01,  1.0917e+00, ...,  1.7000e+01,
          2.0000e+00,  1.0000e+00],
        [-1.4751e-01,  5.5556e-01,  1.0764e+00, ...,  1.8000e+01,
          1.3000e+01,  1.0000e+00],
        [-5.0246e-01,  1.2178e+00, -8.0065e-01, ...,  1.0000e+00,
          3.0000e+00,  0.0000e+00]]),
 array([1, 0, 5, ..., 8, 5, 9]),
 510281,
 510281)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by making labels casted as int

```
input_fn  =  numpy_io.numpy_input_fn(
      x=X_train.astype(np.float32),
      y=y_train.astype(np.int32),
      num_epochs=None,
shuffle=True)
classifier.fit(input_fn = input_fn,steps=None)
```

No idea how it got solved by int but would love an explanation for this ? anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Problem pretty clear described in error message. Try

```
classifier.fit(x=tf.cast(X_train, tf.float32), y=y_train)
```

Also, looks like you using outdated input format with `tensors`. For example of how to convert your input to `input_fn` format look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/ebbf6b3c79ffc0a94b13d95d24aec49fbcef6aee/tensorflow/examples/learn/random_forest_mnist.py#L60).

Comment: Got this now `ValueError: Inputs cannot be tensors. Please provide input_fn.`

Comment: Scikitlearn randomforest runs so smoothly , Why tensorflow is creating so much trouble?

Comment: @Abhay Please, post code, where `X_train` was defined

Comment: Updated the code, Does the scikit-learn method doesn't work with tf classifiers

Comment: Tried that too but it didn't helped

Comment: @Abhay Ok, try to use just `input_fn  =  numpy_io.numpy_input_fn(
      x=X_train,
      y=y_train,
      num_epochs=None,
shuffle=True)`, without type cast.

Comment: Got this again `TypeError: Input 'input_data' of 'TreePredictionsV4' Op has type float64 that does not match expected type of float32.`